# UIMenuController not showing in textView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, uimenucontroller

I'm trying to enable a custom UIMenuController that is activated inside a UITextView. In my viewDidLoad() I have the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.noteTextView.delegate = self
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(enableCustomMenuControllerAtTap(_:)))
    self.noteTextView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
```

The method that handles the gesture is:

```
func enableCustomMenuControllerAtTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tap")
    view.becomeFirstResponder()
    let OP1MenuController: UIMenuController
    OP1MenuController = UIMenuController.shared

    let font = UIMenuItem(title: "Font", action: #selector(pickFont))
    let color = UIMenuItem(title: "Color", action: #selector(pickColor))
    OP1MenuController.menuItems = [font, color]

    let point = gesture.location(in: view)
    OP1MenuController.setTargetRect(CGRect(x: point.x, y: point.y, width: 200, height: 200), in: view)

    OP1MenuController.arrowDirection = UIMenuControllerArrowDirection.down
    OP1MenuController.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
}
```

Next I implemented these methods, as I have seen in many guides:

```
func pickFont(sender: UIMenuItem) {

}

func pickColor(sender: UIMenuItem) {

}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
}

override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if action == Selector(("pickFont")) || action == Selector(("pickColor"))
    {
        if (noteTextView.selectedRange.length > 0) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Can someone tell me why is the menu not displaying? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the menu wasn't showing because I was using a different type of selector in the canPerformAction() method. I had to use the #selector(method) type in order to implement and display my custom menu item actions.